# Session Hijacking over HTTP

Tags: security, http, https

I have noticed a lot of very large websites make you log in using HTTPS and then immediately switch back over to HTTP once I am logged in (myfitnesspal.com, pluralsight.com). If I use a packet sniffer I can see the session id cookie and verify that the request is being sent via HTTP. Doesn't this mean that someone could easily hijack my session if they were listening, or is there something else I am missing? Also, on a similar note is there any reason that I would want to use HTTP over HTTPS other than the additional computation on the server?

Comment: yes you could, and no there is not.

Comment: If you're just serving static pages or you're not moving confidentail/sensitive information back and forth between clients and server, I don't see a need for HTTPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how sessions are being handled. It is possible that two sessions are being handled by the server. One secured and one unsecured.

When you log into these sites they may set two session cookies, one for browsing and one for secure access to admin/account management/checkout areas. The second cookie would be marked as "SECURE" and only be sent over a TLS/SSL connection. When browsing normally, etc only the unsecured connection is used and only to maintain state in the session, but when you go to account management, checkout, etc, then you are switched back to the secure session for those purposes. If it has been too long since your last secure access you may be asked to reauthenticate.

So while it is possible that your browsing session could be hijacked, it is unlikely (if properly implemented) that your account could be compromised as a result.

Comment: Good answer, assuming there are two sessions. Otherwise, hijacked.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can see the Session cookie if its not secure flagged or for example if you see go to wireshark and search for HTTP on your LAN, and you look at the traffic for your example: pluralsight, you just press Follow TCP STREAM on your HTTP connection to the site were after log in you see its on http data stream, and just collect the sessionid and grab greasemonkey(firefox tool) + session hijack : and ctrl+v your collected sessionid and you will see for yourself it there is a vulnerability or not.